# Why are capacitors usually marked on the negative terminal, not positive?

Tags: capacitor, markings

Does anyone know the reason (historical, practical, etc) that polarized capacitors usually have the negative lead marked instead of the positive lead?

I would expect markings to indicate a *positive* potential. Since we commonly ground the negative lead and refer to "ground" as "zero" volts in reference to the rest of a circuit, the positive side would be the "hot" or "dangerous" side, so you would think that would be the marked side, especially on high voltage caps... We color positive wires red, we indicate the "hot" side of AC circuits, etc.  Emphasizing the negative lead seems backward to me.

Comment: Be aware that most Tantalum capacitors have the Positive lead marked.  This is opposite of most other capacitors.  As is often said: "The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why are capacitors usually marked on the negative terminal, not
>   positive?

Here some polarized capacitors: -

[image]

Now you tell me which is the dominant polarity marker?

Comment: Yikes, I did not know that!  I had only been exposed to ones marked on the negative side.  I stupidly assumed all capacitors followed this standard.  So is it just a coin toss to use the negative or positive side, or is something else at play?

Comment: For electrolytic capacitors, unless specifically designed to be insulated, the case (the metal surround) is usually connected to the negative terminal and somehow, through a conventional thought process, you could make an argument that marking the body (case) with the negative sign indicates that the case is negative as well as pointing to the terminal which is negative. That's my "long-shot" of the day!

Comment: Radial electrolytic caps are conspicuously missing from the lineup.  Those are predominantly marked on the negative side.  [On that note, -1.  No hard feelings.]

Comment: Of course I have hard feelings about your seemingly trivial down vote - the picture shows a selection that somewhat undermines the assumption in the question. Did you down vote the question for containing that questionable assumption?

Comment: LOL @NickAlexeev, Andy is simply pointing out that there are myriad capacitor styles and types that mark the positive side.  My limited exposure to capacitors had me thinking they were all marked on the negative side.  Now I know better. :)  Thanks Andy for clearing this up!  When working with alternate types, I will be careful to check datasheets before assuming anything.

Comment: Any chance you cut put a warning in the image to show this is uncommon? Just looked "electrolytic capacitor polarity" on google images, found this image (without context) and now have 10 capacitors soldered on that I need to remove again... oops. Its very high up in the results

Comment: @BartSmienk I'm not sure I understand your comment?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the example image you posted with polarised capacitors with their marking on the positive side comes up as pretty much the #1 result if you look for "Electrolytic capacitor polarity example" (and many other search terms like it). Without context of OP's question people may assume this is an example for all polarized capacitors. Its not your or stackexchange's fault, but Google Image search doesn't provide the context of the question and even if you click on it people may not read the entire question's context. 1/2

Comment: What happened to me is that I found this picture and soldered all my capacitors with the marking on positive line (while this should've been negative). I think adding a warning in the image would save others from making the same mistake as I did, but since its already posted that is likely not possible. May I suggest putting a warning text above the image then? Again sorry for the trouble, in the end its my fault but there is no way I'm the only one who made this mistake because I only saw the image and didn't read :) 2/2

Comment: The question title is this: *Why are capacitors usually marked on the negative terminal, not positive?* so I think it's clear enough.