# Capacitor polarity marker significance

Tags: capacitor, markings

What I am *not* asking is what capacitor polarization means, or how to apply it in circuits.

Is there any physical significance to whether a capacitor uses its positive or negative leads to mark its polarity? Prompted by Andy aka's comment on [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/255596/362218).

Comment: look at the picture in that answer ... only one or two of them have a physical difference between leads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

Generally, electrolytic capacitors with non-solid (liquid) electrolytes (e.g. aluminium polymer) have their negative lead marked whilst ones with solid electrolytes have their positive lead marked *(That's a difference, but can be a long-time tradition, I' don't know)*. But note that marking has nothing to do with having solid or liquid electrolyte i.e. it's not a strict requirement or a physical limitation to put the mark on the negative just because the electrolyte is liquid.

Electrolytic capacitors with solid electrolytes (e.g. tantalum) are more sensitive to surges/spikes due to their electron conductivity *(aluminium electrolytic capacitors generally withstand twice the rated voltage for a few seconds but tantalums don't, for example)*. It might make some sense to differentiate these with a marked positive terminal instead of negative.